# ICollectionView not update in UI

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, collectionview

I am using `ICollectionView` to bind `wpfdatagrid`.`ICollectionView` source is observable collection.  i update the observable collection 5 seconds once. but the collection is modified, but it is not updating to `DataGrid`.

```
public ICollectionView CollectionView { get; set; }

public ObservableCollection<AgentListEntryViewModel> AgentsViewModel
{
     get { return _agentsViewModel; }
     set { _agentsViewModel = value; }
}
```

i set the value to collection view below.

```
this.CollectionView = new ListCollectionView(this.AgentsViewModel);
this.CollectionView.Filter = this.SearchAgents;
```

in `xaml`, I bind observable collection to data grid.

I have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in type of ObservableCollection i.e., in AgentListEntryViewModel

```
private void LoadAgentComponents(List<AgentStateInfo> agentStateInfos = null)
    {
        foreach (AgentStateInfo agentStateInfo in agentStateInfos)
        {
            AgentListEntryViewModel agentEntry = this.AgentsViewModel.SingleOrDefault(agent => agent.AgentStateInfo.AgentId == agentStateInfo.AgentId);
            if (agentEntry != null)
            {
                agentEntry.UpdateAgentEntry(agentStateInfo);
            }
        }
        this.OnPropertyChanged("AgentsViewModel");
    }
```

the above method i am using to update the observable collection.

```
 <DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Background="{StaticResource ControlLightColor}" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                              IsReadOnly="True"
                              GridLinesVisibility="Vertical"
                              VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                              CanUserAddRows="False" 
                              CanUserResizeRows="False"
                              SelectionMode="Single"
                              AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                              HeadersVisibility="Column"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding AgentsViewModel}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAgentComponent}">
</DataGrid>
```

the above xaml i used to bind to DataGrid.

but The datagrid not updated. can anyone help me .

Comment: You need to call NotifyOfPropertyChanged in setter.

Comment: Updating the Collection by adding or the whole collection gets changed?

Answer (score 2):

Ram Nivas,

It appears that you dont have your `INotifyPropertyChanged` applied to your `AgentsViewModel` property.. Should read something like

```
public ObservableCollection<AgentListEntryViewModel> AgentsViewModel
{
     get { return _agentsViewModel; }
     set 
     {
          if(_agentsViewModel != value){
            _agentsViewModel = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("AgentsViewModel"); //or however you are calling your property changed
          }
     }
}
```

Although you may have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your `AgentListEntryViewModel` model you must also apply the same logic to the `AgentsViewModel`.

The reason for this is the Binder will be listening for the notification against the property `AgentsViewModel` and not listening for changes on the properties of each `AgentListEntryViewModel`.

Comment: Can you post the code change in an edit. And also a sample of the XAML binding?

Answer (score 1):

You are `not adding/deleting from collection` (so INotifyCollectionChanged does not come into picture).

Instead you are modifying some property in underlying data class (AgentListEntryViewModel) which is evident from this piece of code:

```
agentEntry.UpdateAgentEntry(agentStateInfo);
```

If you are updating some property say `AgentStateInfo` then that **property should raise PropertyChangedEvent** i.e. `AgentListEntryViewModel` should implement INPC.

But in case you want to refresh complete view, you can call `Refresh()` on ICollectionView instance (not good idea though) once you are done with modifying property:

```
CollectionView.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `INotifyPropertyChanged` event and inherit your Datacontext class from it

then use the following code in that class

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;



protected void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
{
    var propertyName = GetPropertyName(action);
    RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
}
private static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T>> action)
{
     var expression = (MemberExpression)action.Body;
     var propertyName = expression.Member.Name;
     return propertyName;
}
```

and let set your property in an observable collection. So that is it is updated means it will changed in the UI.

```
        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return _userName;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_userName != value)
                {
                    _userName = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(() => UserName);
                }
            }
        }
```

and in  the xaml page declare your control like this

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontWeight="Normal" Margin="2" MinWidth="100" 

Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="2" FontFamily="Calibri" Name="txtKey14" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding UserName}"/>
```

Well now you got an idea of how to update the data dynamically.
Hope it helps....!